# Next round on floating-point rounding

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal, rounding

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/153724/581205) and many others, but not a duplicate. I work with `double`s, which are surely correct to say 6 decimal places and using

```
String.format("%f.6", x)
```

always returns the correct value. However,

```
String.valueOf(x)
```

does not. I'd need to "round" `x`, so that it'd produce the same (or shorter in case of trailing zeros) result as formatting to 6 decimal places. **I don't want the exact representation of the decimal number and I know it does not exist.** Using

```
x = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.6f", x))
```

gives me what I want, but I'm looking for some more straightforward method (faster and producing no garbage). The obvious way for rounding

```
x = 1e-6 * Math.round(1e6 * x)
```

does *not* work.

---

As an example consider the following snipped

```
double wanted = 0.07;
double given = 0.07000000455421122;
double wrong = 1e-6 * Math.round(1e6 * given);
double slow = Double.parseDouble(String.format("%.6f", given));
double diff = wrong - wanted;
double ulp = Math.ulp(wrong);
```

computing these values

```
wanted 0.07
given 0.07000000455421122
wrong 0.06999999999999999
slow 0.07
diff -1.3877787807814457E-17
ulp 1.3877787807814457E-17
```

The problem seems to be that `1e-6 * 70000` produces the best possible result, but it's one ulp away from what I want.

Once again: I'm not asking how to round, I'm asking how to do it faster. So I'm afraid, `BigDecimal` is not the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, but given the fact that `BigDecimal` has a method that does exactly what you're asking, I don't understand why that option is off the table.

Comment: `double` cannot represent `0.07` accurately. The best you can "achieve" is `0.070000000000000007`, and for that you can simply do `double wanted = int(given*100)/100.0`.

Comment: @JoeC Speed (and produced garbage). It doesn't matter that much in my real use case, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `1e-6` is not exactly 10<sup>-6</sup> (it is in fact 0.000000999999999999999954748111825886258685613938723690807819366455078125)

Instead of multiplying by this, you should divide by `1e6` which is exactly 10<sup>6</sup>, then the result will be the closest floating point number to 0.07 (which is `0.07` or 0.070000000000000006661338147750939242541790008544921875).

Comment: WOW! Really so simple?